# Unitest with directives in AngularJs. How can get the value after change by controller in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine, angular-directive

I have a template file, a directives and a unitest file.

In template,

```
<span class="icon-fire"
 ng-click="abcClick()" ng-show="valueChanged"></span>
```

In directive,

```
  function abcDirective() {
        return {
            restrict: "AE",
            replace: "true",
            templateUrl: "abc.template.html",
            scope: { valueChanged: "=" },
            controller: abcController
        };
    }
```

In controller,we have a function for change value at expand.

```
var abcController = [
        "$scope", "$rootScope", "$timeout", function ($scope, $rootScope, $timeout) {
            $scope.abcClick = function () {
                if ($scope.valueChanged) {                       
                    $scope.valueChanged= false;
                    washClothes();
                } else {                       
                    $scope.valueChanged= true;
                    CleanHouse();
                }
            };
```

In unitest, I want to click abcClick() and it'll be change expand value by controller. But the result it's not my expect.

```
it("should call abcClick function and set expand is true", function () {
            var $scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $scope.valueChanged= true;
            var htmlDirectiveWithArgument = '<change-value-button valueChanged="{{valueChanged}}">" + "</change-value-button>';
            var element = $compile(htmlDirectiveWithArgument)($scope);
            $scope.$digest();

            var queryResult = element[0].querySelector(".icon-fire");
            var wrappedQueryResult = angular.element(queryResult);
            wrappedQueryResult.triggerHandler("click");

            var isolatedScope = element.isolateScope();
            var abcResult = isolatedScope.valueChanged;
            expect(false).toEqual(abcResult);
        });
```

abcResult is true. But I expect it'll become false. Because after we call click, It must be change valueChanged to false. because we input $scope.valueChanged= true; before we call click function.

Comment: Don't try and simulate DOM events in your test. Simply call `isolateScope.abcClick()`

Comment: I tried it okie. But how can we set   scope.valueChanged= false; and expect   scope.valueChanged= true after call abcClick() at UnitTest

Comment: I have a solution for it. After we isolateScope(), we transit expand value to isolatedScope and call abcClick() function from isolateScope. The value from scope.expand will be change by isolateScope.